Kentico 13 - routing problem in admin app
I have problem with routing in kentico admin app. When I open home page, layout is visible, but there is no content. I need to go to the /home/index for the content to bi visible.
When I am running site locally, I am able to see content on my /home or /.
I assumed that I am missing something in configuration of routing in my admin app.
Here is the part of a startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                        .Add(new AdminRedirect(Configuration)));

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseKentico();

    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.Kentico().MapRoutes();
   
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "error",
           pattern: "error/{code}",
           defaults: new { controller = "HttpErrors", action = "Error" }
        );

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
}

And this is my HomeController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using LearningKitCore.Models.SupportCenter;
using LearningKitCore.Manager;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LearningKitCore.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly HomeManager _homeManager;

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetTopMenu()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Demo Center", "Demo-Center" },
                { "What's New", "What-s-New" },
                { "Video Tutorials", "Video-Tutorials" },
                { "Shortcuts", "Shortcuts" },
                { "Downloads", "Downloads" },
                { "Trust", "Trust" }
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the HomeController class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="homeManager">The HomeManager object used to retrieve home data.</param>
        public HomeController(HomeManager homeManager)
        {
            _homeManager = homeManager;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves home data and renders the Index view.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The Index view with the retrieved data.</returns>
        [Route("uatsupport_v13_live")]
        [Route("uatsupport_v13_live/Home")]
        [Route("")]
        [Route("Home")]
        [Route("Home/Index")]
        [Route("Home/Index/{id?}")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // Retrieve data using HomeManager
            var (pageLinks, articleText) = _homeManager.GetHomeData();

            // Create an instance of MyViewModel and set its properties
            var newModel = new MyViewModel
            {
                PageLinks = pageLinks,
                DictHomeArticleText = articleText,
                DictTopMenu = GetTopMenu()
            };

            return View(newModel);
        }
    }
}


So I am trying to render the content on the path: /home or / on my admin app
